# AIX: List all ports in /etc/security/login.cfg

Tags: aix

As discussed in [AIX 7.1 Files Reference](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.files/login.cfg.htm), the `login.cfg` file contains two types of stanzas:

- **port:** Defines the login characteristics of ports.
- **user configuration:** Defines programs that change user attributes.

Examples of port stanzas include `default`, `/dev/tty0`, and `/dev/console`.

Is there an AIX command which lists all defined ports in `login.cfg`?

Something like:

```
LoginCFG=/etc/security/login.cfg
awk -v RS='' '/^[^*]+:/ {print $1}' $LoginCFG |\
  grep -v '^[[:blank:]]*usw:' |\
    cut -d: -f1
```

might work, but is there a better way to do this? (say, a special command)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about special command but I think you should try a different regexp:

```
awk '/^.*:$/ {print $1}' $LoginCFG | cut -d ':' -f 1
```

It works fine for my `login.cfg` file:

```
/dev/tty0:
    sak_enabled = true
    herald = "login to tty0:"

default:
    logindisable = 3
    sak_enabled = false
    logintimes =
    logininterval = 0
    loginreenable = 0
    logindelay = 0
    minsl = IMPL_LO
    maxsl = “TS ALL”
    tl    = TS
```